# Can't delete files on win 7, linux is fine?

Tags: windows-7, linux-mint

I've got several files that had been copied from an ubuntu system at one point.

I didn't realize it when I first copied them on my windows 7 machine that there was anything wrong with them. Until I tried to rename them. Which I couldn't. Nor could I delete them. Windows simply tells me

```
Could not find this item
This item is no longer located in <path> Verify the item's location and try again.
```

But, I can copy them around making more copies that I can't do anything with!

At which point I tried to get rid of them.

1. chkdisk found no errors
2. rebooting didn't make them disappear.
3. A suggestion was used to use linux live boot cd. I created one of those, booted up in linux mint 17LTE, and deleted the files.

I could also open them, rename them, delete them and generally use the files. They are perfectly fine.

What's going on with windows and how do I fix that?

Security tab:group everyone, which includes write, modify, read, read&execute checked.
The folder this particular files are in the security tab is empty: "The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed."

Comment: Probably is a problem of permissions. Did you have the permission _to write_ those files? Check with properties attributes write...

Comment: @hastur - updated the question with some more information for you

Comment: Do the problematic files happen to contain prohibited NTFS characters `\/:*?"<>|`, start with a dash, or end with a space or period?

Comment: @steven no, nothing illegal